# Changing date type with PHP

Tags: php, excel

Here's my code:

```
$date_depo = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_depot));
```

So in my excel table I have => **2 nov 16 00:00:00**
and this code changes it to =>   **02-11-2016**

**But** if I have **10 mai 13 00:00:00** it changes it to **01-01-1970**
it means that the value is 0 or something like that, how can I change it to => **10-05-2013**

**Edit:**

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); 
$date_depo = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $date_depot);
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: `mai` should be `may` to be properly parsed by php

Comment: @u_mulder Indeed, but they may not have complete control over that. Therefore, they'd need something else to recognize the language set. Say like set locale maybe (in French).

Comment: i see, is there a way to change that or do i have to write a code that changes all of the months to english?

Comment: @elianero You can try set locale http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309960/change-month-name-to-french --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430767/php-print-month-in-french - and the last one which happens to contain an answer for it that I gave; didn't even know that lol

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! I'm just new to PHP

Comment: @Fred -ii-  it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$trans = array('janv' => 'January ','févr' => 'February','mars' => 'March ','avr' => 'April','mai' => 'May','juin' => 'June','juil' => 'July','août' => 'August','sept' => 'September','oct' => 'October','nov' => 'November','déc' => 'December');
                $resulat= strtr($date_depot,$trans);
                $date_depot_t = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($resulat));
```

Had to replace every month, but it works!